# Unable to connect to recently launched PostgreSQL RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, connectivity, rds

I have an RDS instance that I'm unable to 'psql' (connect) to. I've confirmed the following:

- VPC is vpc5525e931 (10.0.0.0/16)
- Subnets are bbddfoe2, 96979cec (10.0.0.0/24) (10.0.1.0/24) pointing to above VPC above
- Security is set to rds-launch-wizard3, which I opened 5432 to all (same VPC as above)

I've tried connecting to the endpoint via hostname and IP address, both of which fail w/the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "x.x.x.x.x" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any help much appreciated! Also, any thoughts on diagnosing this further would certainly help. It's likely I missed some configuration somewhere.

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? From a server within the VPC?

Comment: Hello, no I'm trying to connect from the outside internet.

Comment: Then is it in a public subnet? Are you using the public DNS name for the RDS instance? Did you enable the "publicly accessible" flag when you created the RDS instance?

Comment: Hello, I did enable the publicly accessible flag and I'm not aware what else (if anything) I needed to setup. I'll confirm again...yes, I'm using the AWS supplied hostname/endpoint. I think it's a public subnet, I'm not sure to be honest, I assumed it is.

Comment: Is it the default vpc, or did you create the vpc manually?

Comment: I received a few errors when attempting to create this instance w/the default VPC. So I had to create a new VPC and a new internet group.

Comment: Did you add anew Internet gateway?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant internet gateway, not internet group.